# css div background become more to left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this css class

```
#asdfasdful li .deleteFood{
    background-image:  url(http://localhost/asdfasdf/public/images/close.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    float: right; right: 10px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I'd need to see the HTML for what's in the image, including the yellow buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add {clear: right;} on each row, or maybe adjust line-height to a larger value.

Try this:

```
#yourOrderFoodsItems ul li .deleteFood {
    clear: right;
}
```

Comment: Show some HTML or a demo. I don't have my crystal ball with me today. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I notice you have a 'right' property defined on the same line as the float property. Could be the source of your bug.

```
float: right; right: 10px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a div with a background image, you'll want to shift the image using the `background-position` CSS property.

[Please refer to the documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/background-position)

```
background-position: -10px;    /* to move the background 10px to the left... I think */
```